# How to open a document multiple times in VS2012?

Tags: windows-8, c#, visual-studio-2012

I would like to know if it is possible to open a source file multiple times in VS2012 Express?
For example I would like to open a UserControl in two views (Code/Design) in two tabs to e.g. put each view on one screen (I don't like the split view that much).

I know that I achieved this in VS2010 by using Window->New Window and I had another tab open with the same source file. But in VS2012 this option is always disabled :(

I use C# for development.

Answer (score 3):

The Window → New Window option is disabled for HTML windows, but I can open 2 different windows for all others (Code Behind, JS, CSS):

[image]

Comment: Forgot to say that I use C# for development

Comment: This should work irrespective of language used.